# About Shiny folders and files organization and why my app is crashing

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Project called `Questions`

The main project folder has:

```
- .proj file
- app.Rp file
- R Folder > a_package.R and b_file.R
```

This is `a_file.R` :

`data <- gapminder`

This is `b_package.R`

`library(shiny) library(gapminder)`

The `app.R` file:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So, when I run the app is necessary to run the libray functions with the packages.

But I didnt know that when I have files in R folder it would run in a alphabetically order.

So the a_file run first. And this make the code crash. But when I change the name of the file to b_file and a_package it runs ok.

Why this? What am I not understand about the R folder?

And also, even if I set:

`library(shiny) library(gapminder)`  on app.R file it runs first the R folder files first.

Is there a way to "force" `library(shiny) library(gapminder)` to run first? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

why dont you put all your libraries and data into one app.R file ? or create ui, server and global file structuredly? because for your case I didnot understand how you run files? in task scheduler?

what you can do:

1. you can merge all necessary libraries/data/buildin functions into one app file
2. create default shiny app structure, ui, server and global file (then you will not need to have order)
3. you can use source function to call other scripts orders which you prefer. for example

```
source("a_file.R")
source("b_package.R")


ui <- fluidPage(
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Please let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thanks for yout time! There is no task scheduler. I think the `source()`solution works. My question is to avoid this situation of running an app and it creashes beacause the `library` function werent called. Because this is the beggining of everything right?

Comment: You are right, so source function is best option in your case